# Count occurrences of values in column 1 based on column 2?

Tags: python, pandas

```
a     Yes  
b     No    
c     Yes  
a     No   
c     No    
a     Yes  
b     No  
b     Yes
```

So how can I get an output giving me a count of Yes and No for each letter in a pandas Dataframe?

```
    Yes    No
a    2      1   
b    1      2
c    1      1
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.col1,df.col2)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben What I ended up using was a groupby.value_counts. Now I have a resulting object. What I'd like to do is create a double line graph with Letter on x, and Yes/No counts for each letter on y. Any idea?